# Where to place register code to zookeeper when using nd_service_registry with uwsgi+Django stack?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, apache-zookeeper

I'm using [nd_service_registry](https://github.com/Nextdoor/ndserviceregistry) to register my django service to zookeeper, which launched with uwsgi.

versions:

> uWSGI==2.0.10
>
> Django==1.7.5

My question is, what is the correct way to place nd_service_registry.set_node code to register itself to zookeeper server, avoiding duplicated register or deregister.

my uwsgi config ini, with **processes=2, enable-threads=true, threads=2**:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /data/www/django-proj/src
module = settings.wsgi:application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.test
master = true
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi-proj.pid
socket = /tmp/uwsgi_proj.sock
processes = 2
threads = 2
harakiri = 20
max-requests = 50000
vacuum = true
home = /data/www/django-proj/env
enable-threads = true
buffer-size = 65535
chmod-socket=666
```

register code:

```
from nd_service_registry import KazooServiceRegistry
nd = KazooServiceRegistry(server=ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_URL)
nd.set_node('/web/test/server0', {'host': 'localhost', 'port': 80})
```

I've tested such cases and both worked as expected, django service registered at uwsgi master process startup only once.

1. place code in settings.py
2. place code in wsgi.py

Even if I killed uwsgi worker processes(then master process will relaunch another worker) or let worker process kill+restart by uwsgi harakiri options, no new register action triggered.

So my question is whether my register code is correct for django+uwsgi with processes and threads enabled, and where to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happened when you use uwsgi with master/worker. When uwsgi master process spawns workers, the connection to zookeeper maintained by thread in zookeeper client can't be copy to worker correctly.So in application of uwsgi, you should use uwsgi decorators: uwsgidecorators.postfork to initialize register code. The function decorated by @postfork will be called when spawning new workers.

Hope it will help.